# GWT SimplePanel can only contain one child widget when working with popup

Tags: java, gwt

I am confused with the simple panel and its only one child widget feature.

The following will cause the exception about the one child widget. How does the popup violate the one child widget rule? If I create an inner class extends the PopupPanel, then there is no more one widget exception.

Thanks

```
Class DashBoardPanel extends SimplePanel{
private PopupPanel popup=new PopupPanel(true);
...
public void initDashBoardPanel(ArrayList<EventDTO> _evtAry) 
{
    Iterator<EventDTO> it=_evtAry.iterator();
    int row=0; int col=0;
    while(it.hasNext()) 
    {
        final EventDTO evt=it.next();
        //every 3 column, next row
        if(col==3)
        {
            col=0;
            row=row+1;
        }
        Image evtPic=new Image(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"photoServlet?photoName="+evt.getEvtPicName());
        evtPic.setSize("200px", "200px");
        Button editBtn=new Button("Edit");
        FlexTable evtTab=new FlexTable();
        evtTab.setWidget(0, 0, evtPic);
        evtTab.setWidget(1, 0, editBtn);
        this.evtFlexTable.setWidget(row, col, evtTab);
        editBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                FlexTable table =new FlexTable();
                table.setWidget(0, 0, new Label(evt.getEvtName()));
                popup.add(table);
                popup.center();
            }
        });
        col=col+1;
    }
    frame.add(new Label("DASH BOARD"));
    frame.add(this.evtFlexTable);
    this.btnPanel.setWidget(0, 0, this.btn1);
    this.btnPanel.setWidget(0, 1, this.btn2);
    frame.add(this.btnPanel);
    this.add(frame);
}
```

But if I create an inner class extends Popup, there is no SimplePanel only one child widget exception.

```
public class DashBoardPanel extends SimplePanel{
private EvtEditPopup evtEditPopup=new EvtEditPopup();
//Replaced the popup by this
public class EvtEditPopup extends PopupPanel
{
    FlexTable table =new FlexTable();
    String evtName="Event";
    //table.setWidget(0, 0, new Label(evt.getEvtName()));
    public EvtEditPopup()
    {
        super(true);
        table.setWidget(0, 0, new Label(evtName));
        this.add(table);
    }
    public void setEvtName(String _evtName)
    {
        this.evtName=_evtName;
        table.setWidget(0, 0, new Label(evtName));
    }
    public String getEvtName()
    {
        return this.evtName;
    }
}
public void initDashBoardPanel(ArrayList<EventDTO> _evtAry) 
......
editBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                DashBoardPanel.this.evtEditPopup.setEvtName(evt.getEvtName());
                DashBoardPanel.this.evtEditPopup.center();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The PopupPanel and your DashBoardPanel are both SimplePanel so you might be adding more than one widget to one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why it is not more than one widget if I use the inner class extending the PopupPanel?

Comment: are you sure you are not overriding some behavior that prevent this from happening, if you can full code sample that might help.

Answer (score 3):

There are other panels that support multiple children like `FlowPanel`, `VerticalPanel`, etc. If there are widgets like `PopupPanel` that only support one child, just wrap the content into one of these panels.

[GWT Showcase • DialogBox](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDialogBox), example using a `VerticalPanel`:

```
// Create a table to layout the content
VerticalPanel dialogContents = new VerticalPanel();
dialogContents.setSpacing(4);
dialogBox.setWidget(dialogContents);
```

Also, you should follow the [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) rule using `Composite` ([custom widgets guide](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets.html)).

Comment: I am trying your tutorial https://dev.to/ibaca/modern-gwt-first-steps-509k but when I run `mvn package` I get error:`Unknown packaging: gwt-app`

Comment: This is bc you haven't added the gwt-maven-plugin properly, the plugin defines this new packaging type.

Comment: I got it to work. Now I want to add server side following the GWT Ajax part of Sockwatcher. What must I do? http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

Comment: I am getting an InvocationException. Would appreciate if you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/67527917/398348